# How to remove a Swift Package Dependency from the Xcode source control navigator

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I tried out a package but decided not to use it. So I deleted the according dependency via Project Settings -> Swift Packagesm which worked so far. The point is, that the according repository is still listed in the Source Control Navigator - below my own project and with a group called "Swift Package Dependencies". How to remove that repository? When I right-click on it the delete button is disabled. When I search the project for the according package I don't find anything...

Comment: ... the point is: the package is no longer visible in the project navigator, but still in the source control navigator.

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution: The file `/Users/<USER>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<APPNAME>/Blueprint.xcscmblueprint` still contained a reference to the package remote. I deleted that file and now the remote repository of the package is no longer shown in he source control navigator!