# Removing Swift Packages from Source Control XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I recently added some Swift Packages to my Xcode 11.3 project manually by dropping them onto the Project Navigator. This allows me to edit out some errors in the source.

[image: Manually added packages in Organizer]

By doing this, Xcode automatically adds these to Source Control.

[image: Packages automatically added to Source Control]

I can't seem to find any way to remove them from Source Control from within Xcode. I would prefer to retain these as dependencies but commit them to my own source control and ignore master/remote.

Fetch and Refresh Status from Git yields:

[image: Repos Locked]

This behaviour is instructed by Apple here: [Editing a Package Dependency as a Local Package](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/editing_a_package_dependency_as_a_local_package)

> To add the Swift package as local package to your project:
>
> 1. Check out your package dependency’s source code from its Git
>    repository.
> 2. Open your app’s Xcode project or workspace.
> 3. Select the Swift package’s folder in Finder and drag it into the
>    Project navigator. This action adds your dependency’s Swift package as
>    a local package to your project.
> 4. Make changes to the local package and your app, then verify them by
>    building and running your app.
> 5. When you’re done editing the local package, push your changes to its
>    remote Git repository.
> 6. When the changes have made it into the package’s next release, remove
>    the local package from your project, and update the package dependency
>    to the new version.

#### Step 5 here is broken. I don't have write access to that repo.

Other things I tried.

I've tried deleting Clean, Rebuild and deleting Derived Data

I've tried [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64900761/how-to-remove-a-swift-package-dependency-from-the-xcode-source-control-navigator) however `Blueprint.xcscmblueprint` doesn't exist.

Comment: What is the Organizer? Did you mean the project Navigator?

Comment: Ah yes, sure did. Thanks, edited.

Comment: Okay excellent. Now could you please explain what "commit them to my own source control and ignore master/remote" means? Are these _your_ Swift packages? Are you in charge of their GitHub repositories? If not, what are you expecting / hoping to do with them with "your own source control"?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I had to make changes to files in the source to fix an issue with the packages. I can’t commit those changes to my own repo, Xcode wants to push to the master of those repos. So i’m left with either removing these packages or forking and and getting a PR merged unless i can just manage the source of these frameworks myself within my own repo which is what I’m asking here.

Comment: If the Swift Package manager integration with Xcode necessitates Packages being kept up to date and bug free - then what is the strategy when the Package has unsolved issues? For clarity, no these aren’t my packages. They’re dependencies in my project.

Comment: OK, you lost me still. What changes? Are you saying you made changes to the _package_ source files???

Comment: Correct. There is a heap buffer overflow issue in one of these packages. This was raised on github in 2018 and remains unresolved.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you seem to be trying to solve is: You want to make changes to package source files in a maintainable way, and these are not your packages.

Clearly, of itself, that is a complete non-starter. These files don't belong to you, in any sense whatever. And as soon as a new version comes down from the remote repo, your changes will be overwritten anyway.

This sort of thing is *always* an issue when you rely on third-party code, especially in a dependency architecture like pods or packages. If there's a problem with the code, you can't fix it; it isn't your code.

One option is to create an Issue at GitHub and try to get the owners of the code to fix whatever the problem is.

Another possibility is to try to write "shim" code in *your* code, such as to fix whatever the issue is by plastering it over somehow.

Alternatively, since this package repo is presumably at GitHub, you can *fork* the repo. Now it *is* your package, and you can set up a dependency on *that* and make changes and push them up to *your fork.* Of course, the original ("upstream") repo may change, but then you will reconcile those changes with yours as a separate operation.

Still another possibility, of course, is to abandon the notion of package management and dependency entirely and just incorporate the desired source files directly into your project. Now they are yours and you can do with them what you like. (Be careful of copyright issues, of course. You may still have to give credit where credit is due.)

Comment: Thanks Matt. Yes, seems like an issue with the dependency manager architecture. So you’re saying I’d need to make my own package from the forked repo? My changes are basically a hotfix to avoid a heap buffer overflow problem that has been unresolved since 2018 looking at the github issues. This is within a package that is a dependency of another package.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like forking is the simplest solution. I'm a little unclear on what to do about the dependency chain; maybe you have to fork everything the whole way up the chain. So if you depend on A and A depends on B and B is faulty, I'm guessing you need to fork B, then fork A to make your fork of A depend on your fork of B, then make your app depend on your fork of A.

Comment: Of course if the maintainers of B were doing this correctly, you'd be able to submit your fix as a Pull Request from your fork and they would accept it (if what you're doing is correct).

Comment: Thanks Matt. Yes, now I think I’m doing a better job of articulating the complexity of the issue. I don’t think I want my packages to be *managed* at all since that requires the entire dependency chain to be in order. As we know, in opensource that really isn’t always the case. Unfortunately though, the Swift Package Manager is becoming more common / unavoidable.

Comment: Well you could just incorporate the source files and throw away the package manager and the dependency part of the thing entirely. Of course, you would not then automatically keep up with any changes upstream, but perhaps you don't care about that; you just want the code. That's perfectly fine, it's open source. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Sure, that's exactly what I'd like to do. So what you might notice is, by dropping in the source files into the Project Navigator - Xcode *won't allow* me to "throw away the package manager". This is the central part of my question, hopefully that helps you answer it!

Comment: That's not what I see at all. You just download the files direct from GitHub, _not_ using any sort of package management, and just drag in _the source files_ with none of the package paraphernalia. Do you see?

Comment: Please be specific about "none of the package paraphernalia" in your answer to improve the quality for others and myself.

Comment: Added extra info to the question @matt - let me know what you think

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. None of what you've added to the question is what I said. Indeed, it's just the opposite of what I said. You want to just grab the files that are the source files; do not show Xcode the package folder and package files at all. If you tell me what package this is, I can give clearer directions if you cannot just follow what I'm saying.

Comment: No problem, was just looking for some clarity. Indeed, what you're suggesting is against Apple's guidelines - so I'd prefer an answer that is in support of those. As a workaround, thanks for your comments. I'll just explore removing pieces of all the frameworks until I'm unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

Download the third party library once. Make your changes. Create a patch file. Put the patch file in *your* source code control. This is followed by lots of manual work when yo want to switch to a different version of the third party library.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good solution. Got a quick reference to this "patch file" for clarity?